# How many rounds are in a minute?

Tags: dnd-5e, time

Let's say a debuff lasts a "minute" on an enemy. We all know a round takes approx 6 seconds.

Is this 6 seconds per person? or just for that particular person.

IE: Let's say it's 4 heroes vs 2 enemies. 1 enemy has a debuff that lasts a minute.

Would the debuff last 10 rounds (aka 10*6 seconds=1minute)
or would the debuff last (6*6=36, so 2 rounds) if we cycle through each person.

Comment: Potential duplicates: [How does a spell that lasts x minutes work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108533/how-does-a-spell-that-lasts-x-minutes-work), [How does time pass in combat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100405/how-does-time-pass-in-combat)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### The debuff would last 10 rounds.

[Time section of D&D Basic Rules Chapter 8](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop/players-basic-rules#howtoplay_1131) (official, online, & free)

[Basic Rules p.69:](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PlayerBasicRulesV03.pdf)

> A round represents about 6 seconds in the game world. During a round, each 
>   participant in a battle takes a turn.

6 seconds for a round, and the round consists of all the turns in that round.

Answer (score -4):

correct... 1 minute equals 10 rounds... 10 mins = 100 rounds... an hour, God forbid a combat should take that long, equals 600 rounds of everybody and every thing taking a turn.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour), it's a useful introduction to the site. Stack Exchange isn't a forum, it's a Q&A site. The "answer" form is for answers to the question being asked, rather than repeat, expand or confirm an other answer as you did (which is why you got downvoted). Your post would be more at its place as a comment, which you will be able to post once you get 15 reputations points.